# Integrating a count-down timer while running Get-Counter performance tracking

Tags: powershell

Would it be possible to display a live count-down timer during a Get-Counter event?

A timer would appear while the following code is running:

```
Get-Counter -Counter `
  "\Processor(_total)\% Processor Time" `
  -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 120
```

I am hoping to have a progress indicator to show how long it will take for performance data to be gathered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## New Answer

Here you go, sorry I misunderstood.  In this approach, we'll start a job to run the Get-Counter operation.  Then, we'll start a While loop, and iterate to update the progress bar.  Since we know that this will take roughly 120 seconds, I've set the counter to be roughly filled by the end of the period.  Should the job complete more quickly, we will end the loop.

Finally, at the end, run `Receive-Job` to get the results from the `Get-Counter` command.

```
Start-job -Name GettingCounters  -ScriptBlock { Get-Counter -Counter `
"\Processor(_total)\% Processor Time" `
  -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 120
 }
$i = 0 
$duration = 120 
While ((get-job GettingCounters).State -eq 'Running'){
 

    #increment
    $i++ 

    #Round the numbers up for a nice output and then Write-Progress
    Write-Progress -Activity "Processing $user" -PercentComplete (($i/$duration)*100) -Status ("Gathering data...")
    start-sleep -Seconds 1 
    }
```

## old answer

`Get-Counter` is for getting Performance Monitor Counters, and not really the cmdlet you're looking for.

The simplest way to display a timeout message or counter is with the `timeout` cmd.

This will display

`Press any key to continue 10, 9 , 8 , 7`

and so on, down to 0, until the action will continue.

You can also display a progress bar to a user, if that is your goal.  Here's a simple example

```
    #sample range of numbers
$users = (1..13000)

#setting up base number
$i=0
 
ForEach ($user in $users){
    #increment
    $i++ 

    #Round the numbers up for a nice output and then Write-Progress
    Write-Progress -Activity "Processing $user" -PercentComplete (($i/$users.Count) * 100) -Status ("$i out of " + $users.Count +" completed "+[math]::Round((($i/$users.Count) * 100),2) +" %")
    }
```

The end result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: I am aware that Get-Counter does not provide a timer. I am hoping to have a progress indicator to show how long it will take for performance data to be gathered. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, I misunderstood.